# How can I require my Android (latest version) phone to require BOTH a fingerprint and a password?

Tags: password-protection, fingerprint

Setting up one or the other is easy, but I can't seem to activate both at once.

Before anyone asks, my primary reason for wanting to do this is security.

Comment: I don't think this is possible; see [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/GalaxyS6/comments/32iiz2/is_it_possible_to_use_fingerprint_security_and/).

Comment: Use a third-party lock screen for a password. Use native lock screen for fingerprint. Keep both of them active.

Comment: @Firelord which 3rd party lock screen is trustless, open source and cannot be prevented by loading at launch?

Comment: This thread is about *How to demand fingerprint + password on login?* I edited the title and body be clearer. I deleted my duplicate therad, archieve here https://android.stackexchange.com/q/174809/9897

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go trough Android's security using only one at once. For example, if you have both Fingerprint and Pattern activated, only one of them is required to unlock the device. However, with third party apps like [Next Lock Screen](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.next) or [Picturesque Lock Screen](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.androidapps.picturesque), you can actually stack them. If you activate Next Lock Screen, Pattern and Fingerprint, you will have to use Next Lock Screen first, then either Pattern or Fingerprint.

Comment: So you cannot do this by default without an extra application. I hope the change will come in Android 8 because the issue is about security.

Answer (score 1):

@Susan
If your phone is rooted and has the Xposed framework installed, you can take a look at MasterLock. It's nearly impossible to remove (installs as system app, is device admin, etc). Though, I can't resist to ask, why want to use two lock methods at once? Only you have your finger prints. An additional number lock seems kind of useless to me.

Comment: Your assumption that "only you have your fingerprints" is not necessarily correct for multiple reasons, but that is outside of the scope of my question. http://www.bbc.com/news/technology-30623611

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you can only use one security type on your phone. If that is the case, I would suggest taking the fingerprint security type, so that way if your phone is stolen, it cannot be accessed. However, there may be apps that you can download to allow you to have more than one security type.

Answer (score 0):

Now I don't know much about this topic but I do know from past experience that the best way to do both is 1 use the phones actual finger print password then download an app that gives you a second password or an aplock best wishes and good luck

Answer (score 0):

If you want two locks (fingerprint and pattern/pin/password) only once, you can restart your device or else as others said you need to add any other security application.

Answer (score -1):

Look for an option in the settings, if this doesn't work out you can install a third party application like applock for adding up a password. :)